# AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession().devices not returning any devices

Tags: swift, avfoundation, swift5, core-audio

I have the following Swift code:

```swift
let devices = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInMicrophone, .externalUnknown], mediaType: .audio, position: .unspecified).devices
print("DEVICES: \(devices.count)")
```

However, when run it prints "DEVICES: 0" to the console.  I'm running Zoom when I run this code, and I see the orange dot in the menu, so I know the mic is in use.

What am I missing?

EDIT: I'm building an app that plays a sound but, I don't want to play that sound if the mic is hot.  For example; if the user is on a Zoom call then playing the sound would be distracting to the meeting.  So I'm thinking if I can determine that some other app is using the mic (I don't care what for and don't need to access the mic itself) then I can temporarily disable playing the sound file.

Comment: Based on your comments to Benjamin, I recommend updating your question to be very specific about what you're trying to solve. Interrogating the system to discover what other apps are doing is almost never allowed, and definitely not supported, so normal tools are unlikely to work here (and it may be impossible). This is an intentional design choice by Apple to protect user privacy. You can generally only tell whether you are allowed to get access the microphone, with limited information about why. With enough specifics in the question, it might be possible, but I wouldn't expect it.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, you have to make sure you have (or the user accepted) the permissions to access the microphone. You can check and request microphone permissions using the AVAudioSession class, also try to verify the permissions you have granted in the General > Your application section.
Another thing you can check if the microphone is actually available for use by your application. Sometimes there are applications, like Zoom in your case, might be using the microphone exclusively, preventing your code from accessing it.

If you can expand your code, you can show how you are using the `AVAudioSession class`. You can use the `requestRecordPermission()` method to request permission.

Also, in order to verify if there is another application who is taking exclusive control over the microphone, you might use:

```
func isMicrophoneInUse(by application: String) -> Bool {
  let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
  let category = AVAudioSession.Category.record
  let options = AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.duckOthers

  do {
    try audioSession.setCategory(category, options: options)
    let activeMicrophone = audioSession.currentRoute.inputs.first
    return activeMicrophone?.owningApplication == application
  } catch {
    return false
  }
}
```

or in a more complicated way, you can use the `AVAudioSession.routeChangeNotification` notification to receive updates when the audio route changes, which may indicate that another application has taken control of the microphone.

Comment: In my case, I'm not trying to record anything but, rather, I want to make sure the mic isn't in use by any other app before I start playing a sound.

Comment: What is `AVAudioSessionPortDescription.owningApplication`? The only `owningApplication` that I know of is for SCWindow. What is this code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the actual problem that you're facing, but I noticed that you're trying to use `[.builtInMicrophone, .externalUnknown]` in `DeviceType`. Both of them are deprecated as you can see in the [`AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/devicetype#3964797). You should use `[.microphone, .external]` instead.